# Text shadow just under text

Tags: html, css

I got on page something like this:

```
<h1 class="page-header">Some text</h1>
```

and CSS is:

```
font-size: 60px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
color: #61430c;
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0 0 100px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-89deg, #7D570F 38%, #452E00 56%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Is it possible to add there shadow under text just to look like simple blured line? Thanks.

Comment: Does [text-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) property not do the job for you?

Comment: @Harry, not with -webkit-text-fill-color.

Comment: and there is problem that I need just shadow like "simple blured rule" more like box shadow

Comment: @Shomz: True, just now tried a Fiddle and strangely enough the shadow appears on top of the text :( But I will leave the previous comment there just to let future readers (potentially answerers) know that this was discussed as an option. Or maybe Geril can indicate the same in question.

Comment: I'm not understanding...do you want transparent text, with only an outside, blurred stroke (no fill)?

Comment: As you can see here: http://postimg.org/image/edgc7t0ir/ This is what i need to have there, right now i have it without that rule under text.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to easily achieve this. My suggestion would be to use the `::after` pseudo-element to add a blurred ellipse/oval below the text (here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqfpdew9/)).

```
.page-header::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 383px;
    height: 6px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0px 0px 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 400px / 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 17px;
}

.page-header {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #61430c;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-89deg, #7D570F 38%, #452E00 56%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Yes thats really good Idea, i was also thinking about it but there is problem with width, those headers will be changed dynamically